# HttpContext is null in asp.net core with Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-2.0, httpcontext

I have created one .net core 2.1 project and I have created a one handler for rabbitmq. The issue is when I make a call to controller directly, everything working fine. But when the handler listens to the event someone published, it fails to call a method which works when we directly call via Controller. I was able to find out the root cause and it is mostly because we are not getting any httpcontext when handler listens to the event. Attaching the screenshot where it clearly shows the httpcontext is null.

[When handler listen to the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTx28.png)

[When I make a call via Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pumOp.png)

Can someone help me why I am getting HttpContext as null when the handler listens an event. For information, I have already added below code in the startup.cs file.
`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Below is the sample code

`var clientservice = _documentManagerService.Create();
var fileDetails = await clientservice.GetFile(FullFilePath, StorageId);`

NOTE: I have injected the documenmangerservice in startup.cs file and it is also available in the constructor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when the handler listens to the event someone published" I am not sure what this means. What kind of an event? There is no HttpContext unless there is an HTTP transaction in flight.

Comment: I have multiple projects and these projects communicate with each other via events. To handle publish, subscribe operations, I have rabbitmq in place. So when one project publishes an event, it will go to the destination project via rabbitmq where rabbitmq will forward the request to destination project. I hope it clear your doubts.

Comment: @JohnWu's comment is still valid - There is no `HttpContext` when the code is running *outside* of a HTTP request. What exactly are you trying to access from `HttpContext`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin: I have added a reference for another project and making a call to a method which is in another project. The request never reaches to that project. The same setup works if I make a request from the postman or any rest client.

Comment: OP, do you understand what it means when I say "There is no HttpContext unless there is an HTTP transaction in flight" ... ? If your code is being invoked outside of a web request, HttpContext will always be null, because it is not handling an HTTP request at that moment. Because there's nothing to put in it... no HttpRequest, no cookies, no headers. Do you get it?

Comment: I don't think you really answered my question: `HttpContext` has a number of properties, such as the URL, the User, Cookies - what is it you're trying to get hold of? We might be able to help you achieve that *without* a `HttpContext`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the information @JohnWu

Comment: @KirkLarkin: I am not directly using any properties of HttpContext but I am calling a method of another project which is more like a rest client. So in this case, I am not getting the output which I should get. The same method if I call from the controller, it is working fine. I have added the sample code in the original post above.

Comment: I suppose you could try implementing your own `IHttpContextAccessor` and providing your own HttpContext that pulls data from somewhere else. I am not sure if that would work, and providing an HttpContext would require a ton of code. The other option is to respond to the RabbitMQ event by self-posting an HTTP request instead of making the call directly.